# Запись в xls файл

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

React ts Требуется заполнить форму имя, фамилия и при submit записывать данные в xls файл в следующую строку. как лучше реализовать? еще не сталкивался с таким

Comment: Во-первых, React не имеет никакого отношения к xls, а значит здесь как минимум два не связанных друг с другом вопроса (и ответы на оба можно нагуглить по отдельности — вы читали хотя бы учебник по React, например?). Во-вторых, нельзя просто так взять и редактировать файлы в браузерном javascript, потому что браузер не предоставляет доступ к файловой системе

Comment: Т.к. браузер не может управлять файловой системой, сомневаюсь, что такое возможно. Есть библиотеки, которые конвертируют данные в xls формат и предлагают файл скачать. Далее уже руками вставлять данные в нужный файл

Comment: @andreymal  а если прочитать файл , добавить строку и сохранить?

Comment: Вы получите новый файл, но не исходный + 1 строка. Новый файл надо будет руками сохранить(допустим, перезаписав старый)

Comment: @SwaD добрый день, новый файл получил, а можно как то сохранять автоматически чтобы не руками

Comment: Браузер будет сохранять скаченные файлы в загрузки. Сохранять автоматом в произвольную папку на ПК нельзя.

Comment: @Swad fs.writeFileSync(`${getContentPath()}${PATH_SEP}reviews.xlsx`, JSON.stringify(workbook)) сохраняет файл автоматически без запроса, но как конвертировать строку в xlsx

Comment: @SwaD смотрите ответ

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранять автоматически ,но как конвертировать файл

```
        const workbook = XLSX.read(fs.readFileSync(`${getContentPath()}${PATH_SEP}reviews.xlsx`))

        let worksheets: any = {}
        for (const sheetName of workbook.SheetNames) {
            worksheets[sheetName] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName])
        }
        console.log('worksheets.reviews', worksheets.reviews)

        worksheets.reviews.push({
            id: 2,
            date: 44902,
            name: 'Иван',
            score: 2,
            review: 'Плохо'
        })

        XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(workbook.Sheets['reviews'], worksheets.reviews)
        //XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `reviews.xlsx`,)

        fs.writeFileSync(`${getContentPath()}${PATH_SEP}reviews.xlsx`, JSON.stringify(workbook))
```

Comment: 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin сохраняется json